# Como fazer uma busca aleatória usando script JPQL no JPA2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, query, jpql

A ideia basicamente é procurar um numero X de entidades persistidas de maneira aleatória, sendo que estas entidades não podem ser repetidas.
A pergunta é, tem como realizar este tipo de busca criando e executando um script JPQL?, ou é necessário implementar uma lógica em JAVA ?

Exemplo

```
public Jogo gerarJogo(EntityManager em)
{
   Jogo jogo = new Jogo();
   public String query = //query 
   List<Pergunta> perguntas =  em..createQuery(query).getResultList();
   jogo.setPerguntas(perguntas);
   return jogo;
}
```

se for preciso implementar a logica em java, não precisa do algorítimo, mas preciso de informações mais técnicas  como, se necessário, buscar o registro com menor ou maior id, entre outras.

Answer (score 1):

Vou responder como se você estivesse trabalhando o mySQL.

O problema é que `RANDOM` não é coberto pela especificação do JPA. Minha sugestão é que você faça uma native query +/- assim:

`SELECT id FROM tabela ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT quantidadeDeRegistros`

E depois, com esses registros, fazer uma jpaQL com `IN`:

`SELECT p FROM Pergunta p WHERE p.id IN :ids`